# Compute array member from variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an array, with (currently) a single object which is computed from other objects in a JSON file.

### My test code

```
// Get JSON data and convert to an object
let myFile = '{"foo": {"bar": "baz"}, "thud": "bar"}';
let myData = JSON.parse(myFile);

// Expect to return baz
console.log(myData.foo.$(myData.thud));
```

### The error returned

```
TypeError: myData.foo.$ is not a function
```

### My end goal

Once this is working, what I'm actually working towards, is to build an array which will contain one or more objects, which have been computed.

```
["baz"]
```

Comment: `myData.foo[myData.thud]`

Comment: `$` doesn't exist as a function in your data, and functions aren't JSON legal, you'd have to send it as a string and evaluate it, which isn't safe

Comment: @TKoL Works brilliantly.  Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the end goal by using

> myData.foo[mydata.thud]

Comment: Thank you. `myArray = [myData.foo[mydata.thud]];` works exactly as I want it to